# ¿Cuál sería la máxima dimensión de las imágenes para cada caso particular?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

¿A qué me refiero?

Yo estoy haciendo un juego en ASP.NET. Cada página aspx la estoy llenando de imágenes:

- Imagen de fondo (full size)
- Imagen al costado arriba
- Imagen arriba en el medio (tipo titulo)
- Imagen que cubre un 65% de la pantalla
- Imagen que cubre 25% de la pantalla (esta al lado de la imagen 65%), etc.

¿Existe algun **estandar de tamaño** para cada uno de estos casos?

*Por ejemplo:*
"Si yo sé que una imagen la voy a usar de fondo de pagina full size, no tiene sentido que supere **1920x1080** ya que con esa resolución se verá muy bien, inclusive en los monitores más grandes".

> PD: Por ahora no me importaba mucho la resolución de mis imágenes,
>   pero se volvió muy lento el juego al momento de cargarlo. Creo que el
>   problema viene por ese lado.

Comment: No creo que esta pregunta tenga una respuesta definitiva. No existe un tamaño estándar para cada uno de esos tamaños porque no existe un tamaño estándar de pantalla. Es más importante que te asegures que el peso de las imágenes no sea excesivamente alto (p.e. reduciendo la calidad o los ppp) para que su carga no ralentice tu aplicación. Quizás te interese tener una imagen intermedia que se pueda escalar, y puedes mirar [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/img#attr-srcset) que te puede servir para no cargar imágenes excesivamente grandes.

Comment: Ahora investigo sobre **srcset**. Gracias